# How can I search grids within a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 100x100 grid of 1s and 0s, and I want to determine whether there are more than 4 0s within any given 3x3 on the 100x100 array. If less or equal this would return true, greater would return False. How can I do this?

Comment: So, the output of your function would be True or False? What have you tried, why did it fail?

Comment: Yep exactly. I haven't got a clue what to do, looking for pointers to start

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 1):

You could also do something like this

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

window_size = 3
kernel = np.ones((window_size, window_size))

test_array = np.zeros((100, 100))
test_array[33:35, 33] = 1
test_array[34, 33:36] = 1

output = convolve2d(test_array, kernel, mode='valid')
threshold = 4
hits = np.nonzero(output >= threshold)
```

Where the "hits" are the top-left corners of the windows.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do a brute force search

```
import numpy as np
grid = np.random.randint(0, 5, (100, 100))

summ = 0
searched = 0
for ii in range(100 - delta):
    for jj in range(100 - delta):
        searched += 1
        if np.where(grid[ii:ii+delta, jj:jj+delta] == 0)[0].size > 4:
            print('zeros found in (%i,%i) through (%i,%i) ' % (ii, jj, ii+delta, jj+delta))
            summ += 1
print('number of sets of zeros > 4: %i/%i' % (summ, searched))
```